# Gitignored development keys causing failed server deployment

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have an Express server coded in TypeScript. The compiled code and pre-compiled code have three files for keys like this (I will show the pre-compiled code and it doesn't use commonjs syntax):

```
    /// dev.ts  - development keys

    const keys = {

       googleClientSecret: "GOOGLE_KEY",

       mongoURI:
         "mongodb+srv://MONGO_KEY",

     };

    export type KeysType = typeof keys;


    export default keys;





     ///  prod.ts prod keys

    const keys = {

      googleClientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,

      mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,


    };

    export default keys;
```

These files are imported into my main keys.js file and a conditional determining the NODE_ENV decides what keys are used:

```
    import devKeys, { KeysType } from "./dev";
    import prodKeys from "./prod";

    let keys: KeysType;


    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      keys = prodKeys as KeysType;
    } else {
      keys = devKeys;
    }

    export default keys;
```

Obviously I compile the files with npx tsc command and I use my dist folder in production with this command:

`NODE_ENV=production node src/dist/index.js`

My Github is connected to the production environment and automatically deploys my code to the server but because dev.ts file is gitignored, I am getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './dev'
>Require stack:
>/opt/render/project/src/server/src/dist/config/keys.js
>/opt/render/project/src/server/src/dist/index.js
>requireStack: [
'/opt/render/project/src/server/src/dist/config/keys.js',
'/opt/render/project/src/server/src/dist/index.js'
    ]
```

It's probably simple to fix but how do i solve this?

Comment: ``require(`./${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`)`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an `import` from `dev.*` at the top of your file. This import does not depend on `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

That means if `dev.*` file is not present (which doesn't in your production), you get the error you mentioned.

So to solve that, you need that import to be called only if its not production.

```
import type { KeysType } from "./dev";
import prodKeys from "./prod";

let keys: KeysType;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    keys = prodKeys as KeysType;
} else {
    keys = require('./dev');
}

export default keys;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Didn't realize you could still use commonJS syntax in later versions